# How to implement something like UITableView reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have a custom control with a a data source similar to how a UITableView works. I have also added a reloadData function to load new data.

I want the reload data implementation to be called once per run loop, to avoid reloading the same data more than once.

This is my current implementation:

```
func reloadData(){
    guard reloadDataScheduled == false else{
        return
    }

    self.reloadDataScheduled = true
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().performSelector("innerReloadData", target: self, argument: nil, order: 0, modes: [NSDefaultRunLoopMode])
}
```

The innerReloadData is a private function which actually does the loading, and sets the reloadDataScheduled to false.

This seems to work most of the times, but other instances it seems to delay more than 2 seconds, which is not what I want.

I need insight into the delay of the runloop or any advice on how to achieve this style of implementation.

Comment: Is this a UIView subclass which could allow you to build on `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: Yes it is a UIView subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use below code in this case.

```
- (void)setNeedsReloadData
{
    // cancel all previous schedules
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(reloadData) object:nil];

    // below codes schedule "immediately run after current fetching on runloop"
    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
- (void)reloadData
{
    // cancel the others schedules
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(reloadData) object:nil];

    // Reload Data
    ...
}
```

U can call `-[XXX setNeedsReloadData]` any time and any times.
`reloadData` will run once per fetching on runloop.

ps. in SWIFT

- before swift 1.1 - `[NSObject performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` was prevented.
- after swift 2.0 - Now it is permitted.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be working as expected. I just wish I could have know why the actual NSRunLoop does not. Thanks.-

Comment: ```[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]``` is convience method for ```NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().performSelector("reloadData", target: self, argument: nil, order: 0, modes: [NSDefaultRunLoopMode])```

You can use any code that U want.

Comment: Anyway, U should cancel previous schedules When firing ```reloadData``` Or ```setNeedsReloadData```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1 you would get more info of RunLoops